# Add Keyboard Shortcuts for R Chunks in Quarto Docs Using VSCode

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, quarto

Is it possible to add keyboard shortcuts for `R` chunks in quarto documents using vscode?

I'm trying to use shortcuts like the pipe operator `%>%` (`ctrl+shift+m`) and others. I thought I should do this by including something like the code below in the `keybinds.json` file, but it doesn't work for me:

```json
    {
      "key": "ctrl+shift+m",
      "command": "type",
      "when": "editorLangId == 'r' || editorTextFocus && editorLangId == 'qmd'",
      "args": { "text": " %>% " }
    },
```

Comment: `||` has a lower priority than `&&`, there are no `()` so write out the Boolean expression

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume `keybinds.json` is a typo in your post (the correct filename is `keybindings.json`).

Provided I have understood you correctly, here is my `keybindings.json`

```json
// Place your key bindings in this file to override the defaults
[{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+m",
    "command": "type",
    "args": { "text": "%>%" },
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
  }
]
```

Ctrl+Shift+m then places "%>%" at the current position of the cursor.

Comment: `keybinds` was indeed a typo. Your answer worked for me, thanks!  :)